# Has the handling of the /etc/issue file changed from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, pam

I have bionic systems that display the lines in /etc/issue on login and re-display if I press **ENTER**.

But, on my focal systems I only get the /etc/issue contents once, it does not display when I press **ENTER**.

How do I get the 18.04 behavior in 20.04?

Comment: @guiverc - my question is specific to moving from 18.04 to 20.04

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you get the contents of `/etc/issue` displayed twice after you login on 18.04? Immediately after logging in and again after the first prompt?

Comment: @muru - on bionic the console displays /etc/issue and every press of the enter key displays it again.  on focal it only displays it once, the enter key just displays a login prompt (no /etc/issue)

this is important because there is system information displayed there that is relevant to the user.

Comment: I'd consider it a bug if the system decided to dump the contents of issue every time I pressed enter (and probably others did too, which is why it's not the behaviour now - though I don't recall this ever happening to me)

Comment: @muru - be that as it may, that's the way it worked up through bionic

Comment: I've been using it since 9.04, and I certainly don't remember anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior has changed in 20.04, the ENTER key only displays a login message but....
Pressing CTRL-C will display the contents of /etc/issue.